# JPA insert value but insert null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, insert, null

Im trying to insert some values in Postgres with JPA using Hibernate. I have a mapped class with Annottions called Reserva and it has a field that is :

`@Column(nullable=false)
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar dataFinal;`

I populate all  the fields of this class, no one is null, but when I call persist(reserva) it throws an error that dataFinal is null, but its not! I set all fields. Anyone knows whats is happening to me? Thanks in Advance!
Tip: When I persist another class that have this class(Reserva)  with(Cascade.Persist) it persists Reserva normally.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is:

```
@Column(nullable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar dataFinal;
```

Comment: no.....but I have another suspicion. My program just instanciate one factory and one entityManager. When I change my program to create many EntityManagers, it persists! But if I have many EntityManager in my program, some entities will not be acessible.

Comment: Ok. In that case, post more code so that we can see more closely what you're doing.

Comment: thank you Tiago but I solved yet. The problem was the way I used my EntityManager. I tryed to insert twice without knowing kkk